# How do I get vscode autocomplete after calling a function with a union as its return type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

How do I get proper editor autocomplete after calling a function that returns a union type?

For example, in the code below, after calling `getProperty<ColorfulOrCircle>()` (line 14), the variable `b` should give show me what properties I can access, but that doesn't happen.

```
1. interface Colorful {
2.   color: string;
3. }
4. interface Circle {
5.   radius: number;
6. }

8. type ColorfulOrCircle = Colorful | Circle;

10. function getProperty<T>(cc: T): T {
11.   return cc;
12. }

14. let b = getProperty<ColorfulOrCircle>({color: "red"})

15. b. ; // NO AUTOCOMPLETE
```

When I hover over `b.color`, I get this error message:
[image]

And when I press CTRL + BACKSPACE after `b.`, I receive only 'random' words.

[image]

How should I type my function in order to have better intellisense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not specifying the generic type but letting typescript infer it, this works perfectly.
But as you can see, this function now requires a generic type in its declaration. If you want to have a function that can take a generic parameter like the original function in your question, check out the playground link where I included one at the bottom.

Code:

```js
interface Colorful {
    color: string;
}
interface Circle {
    radius: number;
}

type ColorfulOrCircle = Colorful | Circle;

function getProperty<T extends ColorfulOrCircle>(cc: T) {
    return cc;
}

let b = getProperty({ color: "red" })

b. ; // AUTOCOMPLETE
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA27YFdPIDeAUMmcgljgFzIDOYUoA5gNzEC+xoksiKqYFASYUJcsihwAJsFx1aIXAFsARtHZdiYAJ4AHAVTyYA8lEHDRyALxojMfMgA+aISIjtiDkAjDB0IMjMEGAAClDoBlC6ADwAKsgQAB6QINJ0dtjGZhbuAHwAFAgItHEAlESk5FAhuFCBxZrExKJgyKo2QSHhkdC6BYQURrQARDXSI8gcZc2qAHTIAPSLyHC4YOiUynqtKADuOADWdM3LyKAUcHQoOui4yHtw4KtdINBwBN6+-oFgABZwNoIJ7IaToZD-YAKLy4Hx+AJdMAAcQgbykmB6UViAGVChVxNVavVkF94YFgmEIlidPFEilUelkLiiiVkOVKhIJDUwHUGgh2BIuFpWhROhSUWiPpi+jSMFkHKZzG5RHiBpQsqNxiNps0EAszmsNlsdiF9kcMn9oCgNuggA)